# Yoast custom feed template as add_feed function?

Tags: feed

I'm trying to make [Yoast's Custom RSS feeds](http://yoast.com/custom-rss-feeds-wordpress/) post display in an add_feed function.

Just putting Yoast's snippet inside add_feed results in:

> ERROR: feedname is not a valid feed template.

I have tried two rewrite functions, but to no avail. What could I be missing?

[image]

Yoast's function untouched:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Feed
*/

$numposts = 5;

function yoast_rss_date( $timestamp = null ) {
  $timestamp = ($timestamp==null) ? time() : $timestamp;
  echo date(DATE_RSS, $timestamp);
}

function yoast_rss_text_limit($string, $length, $replacer = '...') {
  $string = strip_tags($string);
  if(strlen($string) > $length)
    return (preg_match('/^(.*)\W.*$/', substr($string, 0, $length+1), $matches) ? $matches[1] : substr($string, 0, $length)) . $replacer;
  return $string;
}

$posts = query_posts('showposts='.$numposts);

$lastpost = $numposts - 1;

header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
?><rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>Yoast E-mail Update</title>
  <link><a class="linkclass" href="http://yoast.com/">http://yoast.com/</a></link>
  <description>The latest blog posts from Yoast.com.</description>
  <language>en-us</language>
  <pubDate><?php yoast_rss_date( strtotime($ps[$lastpost]->post_date_gmt) ); ?></pubDate>
  <lastBuildDate><?php yoast_rss_date( strtotime($ps[$lastpost]->post_date_gmt) ); ?></lastBuildDate>
  <managingEditor><a class="linkclass" href="mailto:joost@yoast.com">joost@yoast.com</a></managingEditor>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
  <item>
    <title><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></title>
    <link><?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?></link>
    <description><?php echo '<![CDATA['.yoast_rss_text_limit($post->post_content, 500).'<br/><br/>Keep on reading: <a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a>'.']]>';  ?></description>
    <pubDate><?php yoast_rss_date( strtotime($post->post_date_gmt) ); ?></pubDate>
    <guid><?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?></guid>
  </item>
<?php } ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

[Function one](http://xplus3.net/2008/10/30/custom-feeds-in-wordpress/):

```
function myPlugin_add_feed(  ) {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  add_feed('feedname', 'my_feed');
  add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'myPlugin_rewrite_rules');
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'myPlugin_add_feed');
```

and [function two](http://www.seodenver.com/custom-rss-feed-in-wordpress/):

```
function custom_feed_rewrite($wp_rewrite) {
$feed_rules = array(
'feed/(.+)' => 'index.php?feed=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
'(.+).xml' => 'index.php?feed='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
);
$wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_feed_rewrite');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `add_feed('feedname', 'my_feed');` but no my_feed function to actually generate the feed output.

Create a my_feed function and have it call the template to generate the feed output. Like this:

```
function my_feed() {
  include 'path-to-that-template-file.php';
}
add_feed('feedname','my_feed');
```

Then regenerate your permalinks, one time only, by resaving the permalink settings.

Also, you don't need any of that extra rewrite nonsense at all. Just the add_feed is enough. WP handles the rest, and your feed will be at /feed/feedname.

Comment: **(Note to self)** Relevant links: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/feed-modification and http://wordpress.org/support/topic/creating-a-custom-rss-feed

Answer (score 2):

First, correct way is to use [`add_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed), but you should not touch rewrite. `add_feed()` handles that by itself.

Second, you didn't provide your callback `my_feed()` function? I am not sure but from that error message I think it fails to get hooked properly.

Comment: The first thing I tried was wrapping Yoast's script in function `my_feed() { // code to output the feed goes here } add_feed('feedname', 'my_feed');`. After that did not work I tried each of the two rewrites. This is my first foray into feeds, so thank you for letting me know not to touch the rewrite.

Comment: Should there be a callback function?

Comment: @M.Taylor in your code `my_feed()` is callback that will handle feed output (in native WP it includes feed template file from core). Your initial idea seems sound, I am not sure what went wrong with it.